# How to fix azure-cognitiveservices-speech install error in Python

Tags: python, pip, azure-cognitive-services

[image]I am working on azure speech services and currently, I'm facing a problem with this command on Python:
*pip install azure-cognitiveservices-speech*

I get the following error: "Invalid Syntax".

I followed this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstart-python

How to make this work?

This is for Windows 7 64 bits, running Python 3.6 64 bits.
I've tried with Python 3.7 64 bits and got the same error.

Edit: The same error while using cmd prompt.[image: cmd prompt - install error]

Comment: sounds like you are trying to run this inside of python.  try pressing the windows key on your keyboard, typing 'cmd' hit enter, then paste the pip line and press enter.

Comment: this thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows

Comment: I've tried it on cmd but I got the same error. :/

Comment: Question is about `pip`, and has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `speech-recognition` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

`pip` is the package installer for Python, which can be used in command line, not in Python interpreter. On Windows, you can find it in your Python installed path, as the figure below for my Python 3.7.

[image]

So if you have add the `pip` installed path into environment variable `PATH`, you can directly use it in CMD or PowerShell, or you can move to its installed path to use it.

Fig 1. My `pip` path has been added into `PATH`

[image]

Fig 2. Or use it under the path in CMD

[image]

Fig 3. Install `azure-cognitiveservices-speech` successfully via pip in CMD

[image]

Fig 4. Then use it in Python interpreter without any issue, or in other IDE like Visual Studio Code.

[image]